# Can remove default 12:00 time edit devexpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm working in MVC 4 and i use [devexpress](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/).

I use a Data Editor `TimeEdit`:

```
<td>
   @Html.DevExpress().TimeEdit(
   settings => {
     settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "form-control input-sm";
     settings.Name = "HoraInicioFiltro";
     settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "h:mm tt";
     settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
   }).GetHtml()
</td>
```

And in `view` this `timeedit` comes:

[image]

**Problem:**
I want it comes with `00:00` and not with `12:00`

Comment: You have problems with format or with output value?

Comment: Problems with hour default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the time that you want:

```
settings.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Or if you'd like to have 00:00:

```
settings.DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

DisplayFormatString for you would be:

```
settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = HH:mm";
```

Comment: `settings.DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)` dont works :/ But if i try `DateTime.Now` works @AndreiMikhalevich

Comment: I remove `settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "h:mm tt";` and works! Thanks

Comment: @CesarMiguel congratulations!